# How do you set a java.security.policy in Maven pom.xml (coming from Ant)?

Tags: java, maven, ant, pom.xml

In Maven, where would I set the security policy as shown in this Ant build.xml...

```
<target name="runComputer" description="Run a computer">
    <java classname="system.Computer" fork="true">
        <jvmarg value="-Djava.security.policy=policy"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

...if my pom.xml includes this profile:

```
<profile>
    <id>manager</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>system.Computer</mainClass>
                    <commandlineArgs>"hello"</commandlineArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation for [exec-maven-plugin](http://mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) has an example:

```
<configuration>
  <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
  <arguments>
    <systemProperties>
      <systemProperty>
        <key>java.security.policy</key>
        <value>policy</value>
      </systemProperty>
    </systemProperties>
  </arguments>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: Cool that worked. Just had to make sure to put <systemProperties> above <commandlineArgs>.  Thanks.